# dapper.net multiple delete issue

Tags: c#, dapper, micro-orm

I'm trying to delete from two tables with two different vairables within a c# class, but I get the following error message:

> When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id
>   Parameter name: splitOn

The sql statement executes fine when capturing command via SQL Profiler, so I'm stumped.

The dapper code is:

```
 public void DeleteListCode(string listCodeId)
    {
       using (var block = new TransactionBlock())
       {
           // Get the code first
           const string sql = "SELECT ListCode from ListCodes WHERE id =@listCodeId";
           var code = TransactionBlock.Connection.Query<string>(sql, new {listCodeId}, TransactionBlock.Transaction)
              .FirstOrDefault();

           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code)) return;

           const string sql2 = "delete from Lists WHERE ListCode = @code " +
                               "delete from ListCodes where Id = @listCodeId";

            TransactionBlock.Connection.Query(sql2, new {listCodeId, code}, TransactionBlock.Transaction);
           block.Commit();
       }
    }
```

I've successfully managed to use a multi select statement, but this is slightly different in the sense that I use two annonomous parameters.

Comment: As you aren't returning anything on the delete I think you should be using `Execute` rather than `Query`.

Comment: after the first Select where you are using `sql` variable once you have executed that query have you thought about executing a `RollBack` command since on the select you're only returning data and not changing data..? then execute the second statement just as you are doing..? or split the sql2 string into 2 different transactions.. also I think that petelids has a good point try doing something like this `TransactionBlock.Connection.Execute` instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second operation should use Execute, not Query. It isn't a query, basically. That should be all you need.

Comment: @marc-grawell how to use IN by Dapper , if i want to delete multiple row ,  like delete from tablename where id IN(1,2,3,4)

Comment: @marc-grawell if i am having an array of ids like 1,2,3,4

Comment: @MeerDeen `connection.Execute("...where Id in @ids ...", new { ids });`

Comment: @marx-gravell why the dapper.dll could't load if i enable signing on wpf,c# my project

Comment: @MeerDeen for now, try using `Dapper.StrongName` instead - same code, different package; long term, we'll probably make 2.0 strong-named only